# ASP.NET MVC: Is is possible to set a global variable?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a process within my MVC 2 application that takes a large amount of time and alters many rows in the database in the process.

There is a chance that two or more users could attempt to perform this action at the same time, which would lead to undesirable effects.

Is there a way to set a global flag somewhere within asp.net that I can check against all requests to see if the action in question is currently being executed? 
(a bit that I flip prior to running query, and then then flip back on completition)

Or is there a better way of handling this situation?

Thanks

Comment: are you familiar with concurrency control mechanisms in databases? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control#Concurrency_control_in_databases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate.aspx) object - it is part of the [`HttpContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

MVC is built on Asp.Net core.  You can use Application object to store with proper locking.